# df hide ifree, iused, 512 blocks (customize column format, don't show inode info)

Tags: command-line, disk-utility, unix, homebrew, darwin

My default `df` invocation prints way too much information for my needs. I can't find a way to hide this in the man page. It says use the `-i` flag to include it. But when I execute `/usr/local/bin/df` I get this:

```
Filesystem                                512-blocks       Used Available Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                               975093952  719904648 254677304    74% 90052079 31834663   74%   /
devfs                                            368        368         0   100%      637        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                                         0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home                                      0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /home
/dev/disk3s1                               242555008  206423680  36131328    86%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/SERIALS
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/ubuntu
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Large_backup
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Large
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Unsorted
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Record
map -static                                        0          0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /Volumes/Documentaries
192.168.1.2:/                              115345392   86998112  22441976    80%   421924  3249100   11%   /Volumes/ubuntu
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Documentaries  488397160  446990432  41406728    92%    15979 20720153    0%   /Volumes/Documentaries
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Record         625121216  625121216         0   100%   125517    38323   77%   /Volumes/Record
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Unsorted       625137280  604966376  20170904    97%   346496 10099404    3%   /Volumes/Unsorted
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Large         1953520000 1949403312   4116688   100%  1379836  2218604   38%   /Volumes/Large
192.168.1.2:/media/myusername/Large_backup   115345392   86998112  22441976    80%   421924  3249100   11%   /Volumes/Large_backup
```

How do I hide all these extra columns? (come to think of it, how do I get rid of those useless `map -static` rows too?)

Extra info:

`uname -a` output:

```
Darwin myusername-Mac-mini.local 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 Macmini6,1 Darwin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard macOS `df` supports an `-P` option (which suppresses most of the things you don't want) so you could run

```
df -P | grep -v 'map -static'
```

Explanation of option (from `man df`):

```
-i  Include statistics on the number of free inodes.
    This option is now the default to conform
    to Version 3 of the Single UNIX Specification
    (``SUSv3'') Use -P to suppress this output.

-P  Explicitly  use 512 byte blocks, overriding any BLOCKSIZE specifi-
    cation from the environment.  This  is the same as the -b option.
    The -k option overrides this option.
```

Comment: Perfect, I'll accept as soon as the site allows me to. I'd forgotten about `grep -v` :) As for `-P`, it seems like a bit of a mistake that this isn't the default mode.

Comment: The man page says: -i *"is now the default to conform to Version 3 of the Single UNIX Specification (``SUSv3'') Use -P to suppress this output."*

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on `GNU coreutils 8.28  September 2017  DF(1)`

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat The standard macOS `df` is different from the GNU version, the answer refers to the macOS version.